# ¿Cómo organizar grants usuarios de postgresql?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Estoy configurando una *BD postgresql* en la que tengo los siguientes usuarios:

```
-postgres (superusuario)
-admin (usuario administrador)
-rol_lector
-rol_ejecutor
-lector
-ejecutor
```

Como la intención es tener varios usuarios lectores/ejecutores he creado el `rol_lector` y el `rol_ejecutor` que tienen la opción `nologin` activada para ser usados como grupos.

De esta manera postgres manda sobre admin,admin sobre los dos grupos, y estos sobre sus usuarios. Todos con no `inherit` para evitar líos a excepción de lector y ejecutor, porque pretendo que hereden todo lo de `rol_lector` y `rol_ejecutor`.

Mi problema es que a pesar de crear una tabla con admin, y ejecutar:

```
grant select on customer to rol_lector
grant select on customer to rol_ejecutor
grant rol_lector to lector
grant rol_ejecutor to ejecutor
```

Ni el usuario `lector`, ni el usuario `ejecutor` pueden encontrar la tabla `customer` al realizar un `select`. Sin embargo los roles `rol_lector` y `rol_ejecutor` si que tienen los privilegios asignados y los ven.

Hay alguna manera de que al dar `grants` a un grupo los usuarios que hay por debajo los hereden? Es decir, al ejecutar: `grant select on rol_lector` se autoejecute `grant select on lector` además de esta misma operación para cada usuario asociado a rol_lector.

**Edito**

Primero de todo disculpad si parece muy amplia, sin embargo creo que estaba claro el conjunto de acciones que he hecho y demás sin embargo, replanteo la estructura en si.

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que estas en Stack Overflow, el cual a diferencia de sitios como Yahoo Respuestas, no es un sitio donde preguntes algo y esperes ayuda sin siquiera mostrar algo de codigo, algo de esfuerzo, para asi poder ayudarte, **muestranos que has hecho, que errores tienes durante el proceso**, muestranos el codigo, para asi poder ayudarte efectivamente.

Comment: En contexto de tu ultima pregunta, estas usando algo como `GRANT group_role TO role1, ... ;` ? Aparte de eso no veo mucho sentido que preguntas que privilegios deberías dar a que grupo sin que presentas un concepto de seguridad que tienes en mente.

Comment: @IvanBotero Ya esta editado, a ver si ahora os dice más.